# Are there any decent developer tools for Lua?

Tags: lua, visual-studio-code, luajit

Lua is a wonderful language and I enjoy writing code in it. I am currently working on a significant project that has a lot of files and code, primarily Lua, and I was wondering if there are any dev tools for Lua?

I am currently using Visual Studio Code and I have Lua syntax highlighting and linting via luacheck, but that is very basic tooling. I am wanting something with project awareness so that if I write a Lua module, my text editor/IDE is immediately aware of that module and can suggest it to me via auto-complete or track inferred data types through code so it can auto-complete module functions, that sort of thing. I know it is a lot more difficult to make such tools for dynamically typed languages so I am wondering it's been done for Lua? I can't seem to find much myself.

I did a quick look on ZeroBrane's feature list but I didn't see anything that stood out to me as "project awareness". Perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: How could you having Lua module source file predict (without loading the module) which fileds would be inside the module table?  Such information is available only in runtime.

Comment: Well, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Eclipse has built a specific IDE for Lua, however i'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean.
https://www.eclipse.org/ldt/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned by my experience using Lua - almost four years already - I've never seen this kind of feature in any of the text editors I had used [ Notepad++, VS Code, Atom Editor, Sublime Text 2 ].